# How to check for sibling class - jQuery

Tags: jquery

How can I hide prev/next controller if "li.item:first" or "li.item:last" has "active" class

```
<ul class="carousel">
    <li class="item active"><img src="ab.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="cd.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="ef.jpg" /></li>
    <li class="item"><img src="gh.jpg" /></li>
</ul>

<!-- Controls -->
<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="prev">
    <span class="icon-prev"></span>
</a>
<a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel" data-slide="next">
    <span class="icon-next"></span>
</a>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great answers here is an alternative solution, I slightly change the above code and remove duplication.

[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7EYWf/2/)

css

```
.carousel .item
{
    display: none;
}
.carousel .item.active
{
    display: block;
}
```

jquery

```
$(function()
 {
    $('.carousel-control').click(function(event) 
    {
        event.preventDefault();

        var $this               = $(this)
        var direction           = $this.data('slide');
        var $items              = $('.carousel .item');
        var $activeItem         = $items.filter('.active');
        var $nextItem           = $activeItem[direction]();
        var hasItem             = $nextItem.length !== 0;
        var shouldHideControl   = $nextItem.is(':first-child') || $nextItem.is(':last-child');
        var $controls           = $('.carousel-control');

        $controls.show()

        if(hasItem)
        {
           $items.removeClass('active');
           $nextItem.addClass('active');
        }

        if(shouldHideControl)
        {
            $this.hide();
        }

    }); 
});
```

Comment: thanks for making it so modular :) I am still running with the issue. pls check the screenshot on the top.

Comment: @Syed Your looking at an older version of my demo. Please click on the link again. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You could do it this way:

```
$(".right").click(function() {
  if($(".active").is(":last-child"))
  {
    $(this).hide();
    $(".left").show();
  }
}
```

And then the opposite (swap lefts and rights) for the "previous" control.

Comment: I'm not too proud to upvote this answer. Much better and clearer.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do it:

```
if($('li.item:first').hasClass('active')) {
   $('a.carousel-control.left').hide();
}else {
   $('a.carousel-control.left').show();
}

if($('li.item:last').hasClass('active')) {
   $('a.carousel-control.right').hide();
}else {
   $('a.carousel-control.right').show();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
if $('li.item:first').hasClass('active') { $('a.left.carousel-control').toggle(); }
if $('li.item:last').hasClass('active') { $('a.right.carousel-control').toggle(); }
```

Not a complete solution, but should get you started. Just work with those in your click handlers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to do this each time your active class changes, i.e. Each time the carousel changes slide.

```
// Show both by default
$(".left, .right").show();
// If the first is selected, hide the left
if($("li.item:first").hasClass("active")) $(".left").hide();
// If the last is selected, hide the right
if($("li.item:last").hasClass("active")) $(".right").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can start by identifying the active `li` first and then check whether it is the first or last in the current `ul`:

```
$('.left.carousel-control').toggle(!$('li.active').is(':first-child'));
$('.right.carousel-control').toggle(!$('li.active').is(':last-child'));
```

http://jsfiddle.net/949SS/4/